# HASingleton fails to lookup JNDI bean

Tags: java, timer, jboss

I am trying to deploy a HASingleton on a JBoss6.4. I have followed [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Migration_Guide/Implement_an_HA_Singleton.html) tutorial to come up with the following:

I create a Service which is supposed to start a timer (own timer interface), by injecting the timer bean through JNDI.

```
public class HATimerService implements Service<String> {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HATimerService.class);

    private final AtomicBoolean started = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private ServiceName serviceName;
    private final InjectedValue<ServerEnvironment> env = new InjectedValue();

    private String JNDI = "java:global/my-ear/my-module/MyTimer"

    public HATimerService() {
        serviceName = ServiceName.JBOSS.append(new String[]{"my", "ha", "singleton", "MyHaService"});
    }

    public String getValue() throws IllegalStateException, IllegalArgumentException {
        return "";
    }

    public void start(StartContext context) throws StartException {
        if(!started.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            throw new StartException("The service is still started!");
        } else {
            try {
                InitialContext e = new InitialContext();
                TimerScheduler myTimer = (TimerScheduler)e.lookup(JNDI);
                timer.startTimer();

            } catch (NamingException var6) {
                throw new StartException("Could not initialize timer", var6);
            }
        }
    }

    public void stop(StopContext context) {
        if(started.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
            try {
                InitialContext e = new InitialContext();
                ((TimerScheduler)e.lookup(JNDI)).stopTimer();
            } catch (NamingException var4) {
                logger.error("Could not stop timer", var4);
            }
        }

    }

    public ServiceName getServiceName() {
        return serviceName;
    }

    public InjectedValue<ServerEnvironment> getEnvironment() {
        return env;
    }
}
```

I also have an activator which activates the service.

```
public class HATimerServiceActivator implements ServiceActivator {
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public HATimerServiceActivator() {
    }

    public void activate(ServiceActivatorContext context) {
            HATimerService service = new HATimerService();
            this.log.info(service.getServiceName() + "HATimerService will be installed");

            SingletonService singleton = new SingletonService(service, service.getServiceName());
            singleton.build(new DelegatingServiceContainer(context.getServiceTarget(), context.getServiceRegistry()))
                     .addDependency(ServerEnvironmentService.SERVICE_NAME, ServerEnvironment.class, service.getEnvironment())
                     .setInitialMode(Mode.ACTIVE)
                     .install();
    }
}
```

The timer bean, HATimerService, and the HATimerServiceActivator are all deployed in an ear called `my-ear`. In the log files I can see:

```
JNDI bindings for session bean named MyTimer.... :
java:global/my-ear/my-module/MyTimer
```

However, every once in a while (approx. 1/3 of all deploys), this setup fails due to a `NameNotFoundException` where the JNDI lookup fails. The full exception is: `Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Error looking up my-ear/my-module/MyTimer, service service jboss.naming.context.java.global.my-ear.my-module.MyTimer is not started`

My guess is that this can be some sort of race condition where the bean isn't registered in the JNDI-tree yet. How can I make the service wait with the lookup until the bean is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there exists a possibility to create dependencies on deployment units. When creating the `SingletonService`, the following dependency can be added:

```
ServiceName ejbDependency = ServiceName.of("jboss", "deployment", "subunit", "my-ear.ear", "my-module.jar", "component", "MyTimerBean", "START");
singleton.build(new DelegatingServiceContainer(context.getServiceTarget(), context.getServiceRegistry()))
                 .addDependency(ServerEnvironmentService.SERVICE_NAME, ServerEnvironment.class, service.getEnvironment())
                 .setInitialMode(Mode.ACTIVE)
                 .addDependency(ejbDependency)
                 .install();
```

As long as `ejbDependency` is a correct dependency, the lookup will be performed after bean start.